# Best GLM model approximating a XGboost model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, boosting

Let's say I have a **XGboost model** ( using python ) with y a numeric variable explained by x1 ... xn categorical variables.

I would like to find a **GLM model** close to that model i.e. having an evaluation score on test set close to the original model score ( on test set ).

```
model = smf.glm( formula = "y ~  C( x1 ) + ... + C( xn )" , family = sm.families.Gamma( link = sm.genmod.families.links.log() ) , data = df_train )
```

How could I proceed to get that GLM model ?

Comment: Best you can do is a GAM. And even that won't be the same as the booster. A GLM, with its strictly linear combination of features, is too restrictive.

Comment: Having a GLM is a constraint. My purpose is to approximate one model (XGB) with another (GLM).

Comment: A GAM is a GLM with an expanded feature basis. Otherwise, just try to have a GLM with linear features to model the output of the XGBoost.